# Cassandra - "Batch is too large" exception

Tags: cassandra, datastax

We are using Cassandra batch statement to persist data. We are getting "Batch too large" exception.
I understand that data in batch size is exceeding the batch size fail threshold.
I need help in calculating the size of the batch. Is there any way we can find out what is the exact size of data passed in batch?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a simple way for an end-user to calculate the size of a batch because it's based on the serialised size of all the mutations in the batch.

A complicating matter is that batch mutations could be any combination of `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` of any combination of columns, row or partition.

As a side note in case you're not already aware, CQL batches are not an optimisation compared to use of batches in RDBMS as I've discussed in https://community.datastax.com/questions/5246/. CQL batches should only be used to keep related partitions in sync across denormalised tables as I've explained in https://community.datastax.com/articles/2744/. Cheers!

Comment: it's possible to get an approximate size of the batch by calculating the size of individual statements, but this depends on specific driver

Comment: Thanks Alex. It is informative and useful. I have another question which is extension of the existing one. I am trying to persist ~10MB of data using one insert statement in a table. Table has a Map type column which can have ~20K entries. I am getting an exception that "it is exceeding max mutation size of 32MB". I am trying to find out how mutation size can be more than 32 MB for 10MB data.  Is there any way to identify that what can be the max size of data persisted in a row.